# Hollow Cube Cuts

Tags: geometry, dissection

[image]

The 2x2x2 inches seamless hollow cube with aluminum surfaces can be cut using a box knife. How to cut it into 4 pieces that can be bend to form smaller 1 inch cubes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be done like this:

> [image]
>  Only one of the cubes is shown, the thick lines are cuts, the thin lines are where it can fold to make a small cube. You can cut four of these shapes from the large cube, centred on non-adjacent vertices.